# python mysql script: DataError: (1366, "Incorrect integer value:

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database

I'm attempting to write a python script that imports a csv data file into a mysql database using phpmyadmin. I get this error message: DataError: (1366, "Incorrect integer value: 'time' for column `assignment2`.`schlumberger`.`time` at row 1")

Heres the code I used:

```
import pymysql
import csv

conn = pymysql.connect(host = 'xxxx', user = 'root', password = '', autocommit = True, port = xxxx)

csv = csv.reader(open('data-large-b.csv'))

try:
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        SQLCreateDatabase = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS Assignment2"
        
        cursor.execute(SQLCreateDatabase)
        
        conn.select_db('Assignment2')
        
        SQLCreateTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS schlumberger(time INT, DISCHARGE_PRESSURE DEC, INTAKE_PRESSURE DEC, INTAKE_TEMPERATURE DEC, MOTOR_TEMP DEC, VSDFREQOUT DEC, VSDMOTAMPS DEC, DISCHARGE_PRESSURE1 DEC, INTAKE_PRESSURE1 DEC, INTAKE_TEMPERATURE1 DEC, MOTOR_TEMP1 DEC, VSDFREQOUT1 DEC, VSDMOTAMPS1 DEC, DISCHARGE_PRESSURE2 DEC, INTAKE_PRESSURE2 DEC, INTAKE_TEMPERATURE2 DEC, MOTOR_TEMP2 DEC, VSDFREQOUT2 DEC, VSDMOTAMPS2 DEC, CHOKE_POSITION INT, PRESSURE1 INT, PRESSURE2 DEC, TEMPERATURE1 INT, TEMPERATURE2 INT, WATER_CUT INT, LIQUID_RATE INT, WATER_RATE DEC, OIL_RATE DEC, CHOKE_POSITION1 INT, PRESSURE11 INT, PRESSURE22 INT, TEMPERATURE11 INT, TEMPERATURE22 INT, WATER_CUT1 DEC, LIQUID_RATE1 INT, WATER_RATE1 DEC, OIL_RATE1 DEC)"
        
        cursor.execute(SQLCreateTable)
        
        for row in csv:
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO schlumberger VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', row)
            
finally:
    conn.close()
```

Can someone please help me figure out why this won't upload? Thanks!

Comment: you csv seems to have a header line so skip it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your csv has a Header line so skip it as the first row needs an int and it finds text

```
import pymysql
import csv

conn = pymysql.connect(host = 'xxxx', user = 'root', password = '', autocommit = True, port = xxxx)

csv = csv.reader(open('data-large-b.csv'))

try:
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        SQLCreateDatabase = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS Assignment2"
        
        cursor.execute(SQLCreateDatabase)
        
        conn.select_db('Assignment2')
        
        SQLCreateTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS schlumberger(time INT, DISCHARGE_PRESSURE DEC, INTAKE_PRESSURE DEC, INTAKE_TEMPERATURE DEC, MOTOR_TEMP DEC, VSDFREQOUT DEC, VSDMOTAMPS DEC, DISCHARGE_PRESSURE1 DEC, INTAKE_PRESSURE1 DEC, INTAKE_TEMPERATURE1 DEC, MOTOR_TEMP1 DEC, VSDFREQOUT1 DEC, VSDMOTAMPS1 DEC, DISCHARGE_PRESSURE2 DEC, INTAKE_PRESSURE2 DEC, INTAKE_TEMPERATURE2 DEC, MOTOR_TEMP2 DEC, VSDFREQOUT2 DEC, VSDMOTAMPS2 DEC, CHOKE_POSITION INT, PRESSURE1 INT, PRESSURE2 DEC, TEMPERATURE1 INT, TEMPERATURE2 INT, WATER_CUT INT, LIQUID_RATE INT, WATER_RATE DEC, OIL_RATE DEC, CHOKE_POSITION1 INT, PRESSURE11 INT, PRESSURE22 INT, TEMPERATURE11 INT, TEMPERATURE22 INT, WATER_CUT1 DEC, LIQUID_RATE1 INT, WATER_RATE1 DEC, OIL_RATE1 DEC)"
        
        cursor.execute(SQLCreateTable)

        for row in csv[1:]:
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO schlumberger VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', row)
            
finally:
    conn.close()
```