# pymysql.err.DataError: (1366, "Incorrect integer value:

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

Getting this error, while trying to sent information to database via this code in python:

```
with open('ypatybes_paruosta.csv', encoding='utf-8') as data2:
    csvreader = csv.reader(data2, delimiter = ';')
    next(csvreader)
    for row in csvreader:
        print(row)
        cursor.execute(
                'INSERT INTO flat_features(flat_id, features_id) VALUES (%s, %s)', row)
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
```

There's only to values, but one of the value (feature_id), have empty value. And for some reason it doesnt like it. 
This is what i see in output window before getting mentioned error:

```
['1', '5']
['2', '5']
['2', '3']
['3', '']
```

Can someone help with that ? Thanks !

P.S. I saw solution here [python mysql script: DataError: (1366, "Incorrect integer value:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68415899/python-mysql-script-dataerror-1366-incorrect-integer-value) but it doesnt help in my case

Table creation code in mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE flat_features(
flat_features_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
flat_id INT NOT NULL,
features_id INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(flat_features_id),
CONSTRAINT fk_flat_features FOREIGN KEY(flat_id) REFERENCES flats(flat_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
CONSTRAINT fk_featuresID FOREIGN KEY(features_id) REFERENCES features(features_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE 
);
```

Comment: Integers shouldn't be quoted. I suggest using null rather than empty.  Can you post `show create table flat_features`  ?

Comment: Updated question. And i cant use null

Comment: Then, how should an empty CSV cell migrate to a NOT NULL column? Skip the row? If so use `if`. BTW -Only *you* can answer this question given table design and data source is in your hands!

Comment: I think you have to make some changes. Your column `features_id INT NOT NULL`  is declared as int and you are inserting strings, remove the quotes. If you still want not null, add a default value, like `features_id INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0`

Comment: What should `''` store into an `INT`?  `NULL`?  `0`?  Well, sounds like MySQL does not want to do either.